# How to find words in pandas? Or the combination of two words?

Tags: python, pandas, string, pattern-matching

I need to find the combination of two words from a text and also the list next words. For example, I have df like this:

```
id                 date                     text
1                  1.1.20                   this is a sweet cat.
2                  1.1.20                   the cat is sweet.
3                  2.1.20                   sweet dogs are difficult to find.
4                  3.1.20                   I love sweet cats.
```

First I need to find the combination of two words... For example "sweet cat"

I think I can do by using `str.contains` but it's not working properly... It's missing a lot of rows.

The second thing I want to search the word and it generates the list of searched words with the word next to it.

For example I search `df[df['text'].str.contains('sweet')]` then it should genrate list like this:

```
list
['sweet cat', 'sweet', 'sweet dogs', 'sweet cats']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.str.split`:

```
d = df[df['text'].str.contains('sweet')]

d.text.apply(lambda x: 'sweet ' + x.split('sweet')[-1].split()[0].strip('.')).tolist()
```

Output:

```
['sweet cat', 'sweet ', 'sweet dogs', 'sweet cats']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['text'].str.extract('(sweet\s*\w*|sweet)', expand=False).tolist()
# ['sweet cat', 'sweet', 'sweet dogs', 'sweet cats']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `re` module:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentences': ['this is a sweet cat.', 'the cat is sweet.', 'sweet dogs are difficult to find.', 'I love sweet cats.']})

kw = 'sweet'
r = re.compile(r'\b({})\s*(\w*)'.format(re.escape(kw)))

print( df['sentences'].apply(lambda x: [' '.join(t).strip() for t in r.findall(x)]).explode().tolist() )
```

Prints:

```
['sweet cat', 'sweet', 'sweet dogs', 'sweet cats']
```